How far away is too far for a sump pump check-valve?
When installing the check-valve for a sump pump they say to place the valve as close to the sump pump's discharge outlet as possible, but beyond this sensible advice, is there a distance that is considered unsafe?  Beyond water flowing back into the pit, can the backwards flow of water damage the pump in any way?
Also, how much HP (horsepower) is needed for a double check-valve system?  Let's say one is directly connected to the discharge outlet, and the second is a few feet higher.  Does 1/4 or 1/3 HP motor supply enough force?

Usually it is very close to the pump, immediately above the pit or even inside it. Why the question?  There are some problems with putting it much farther. A theoretical answer without knowing why the question won't be useful.  But very briefly, the volume of water before the check valve reduces the effective size of the pit and increases pump cycle time correspondingly.

@jay613 there is a rubber boot connecting pvc at about 2' from the base of pump....i figure i can replace the boot with a new check-valve to minimize my work...

Based on a comment to the question, I'm answering about relatively reasonable distances ... say from an inch to a few feet above the pump.  Not 30 feet away.
With two feet, versus say two inches, there is no safety issue.  The only issue is the volume of water in the pipe, before the check valve, will recycle back into the sump pit.  With a reasonably sized pit and a correctly configured float valve, two feet of two-inch pipe is not enough to matter.   If the pit is unusually small or the float valve high/low distance is small, I guess your two feet of pipe could be up to maybe 5% of the discharge volume ... so your pump will work 5% harder.   (I once lived in a house with a sump pit that was a 5 gallon paint bucket.  There, an extra 2 feet of pipe  would make a BIG difference.  Just don't do that.)
I don't think a second check valve will add any significant amount of back pressure but I think the redundancy is not called for.   Failure of the check valve is not disastrous.  It just results in high cycling of the pump, which you should be able to hear or detect with a cheap energy monitor.  A once per decade non-disastrous failure doesn't call for extra complication.

my vertical lift is about 10', so if the check-valve fails there is considerable backflow...

If I was building mine from scratch I'd buy a transparent check valve and place it just above the lid of the pit.
